# Adressing tuples of floats in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a list of tuples (Latitude and Longitude) which I want to draw from randomly and then unpack to address each element of the tuple in a for loop. As both belong together, I cannot draw randomly from two seperate lists as I need the matching elements.

```
list_geo = [(50.111, -7.222), (50.222, -7.333)]

x = random.choice(list_geo) # until here, everything works fine

for a, b in x:
   print(a - 1)
   print(b + 1)
```

As they are floats, I cannot work with them this way. What is a good way to solve this? First changing them to strings, unpack them and then back to float?

Comment: just unpack them, don't *loop* and unpack the result, if you *loop over a tuple* it gives you the individual elements, which cannot be unpacked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unpack the tuple directly:

```
a, b = random.choice(list_geo)
print(a - 1)
print(b + 1)
```

Your approach was trying to unpack a single float value into `a` and `b` which naturally fails.